# Columna fija con la misma altura que la fila que la contiene

Tags: html, css

Tengo un `td` con posición absoluta para mantener fija una columna, ¿cómo puedo hacer que tenga la misma altura que el `tr` en el que está contenido?

Mi código:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.tabla-responsive {
  margin: 2em auto;
}

.tabla-responsive table {
  border: solid 1px steelblue;
}

.tabla-responsive thead th {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.tabla-responsive tbody tr {
  background-color: beige;
}

.tabla-responsive tbody tr td:first-child,
.tabla-responsive thead tr th:first-child {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.tabla-responsive tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: azure;
}

.wrapper-fixed-table {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.tabla-responsive {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.tabla-responsive table {
  min-width: 600px;
}

.tabla-responsive table::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 10em;
}

.tabla-responsive table th:first-child::after,
.tabla-responsive table th:first-child::before,
.tabla-responsive table td:first-child::before,
.tabla-responsive table td:first-child::after {
  content: "";
}

.tabla-responsive table thead th:first-child,
.tabla-responsive table tbody td:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  z-index: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-fixed-table">
  <div class="tabla-responsive">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Apellidos</th>
          <th>Edad en que se realizo el registro ante la sociedad tributaria antes SAT</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Micael</td>
          <td>Marz</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Reauserc hertzz marcuam refell thire secodn martz</td>
          <td>Rodriguez</td>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

El resultado es el siguiente, quiero hacer que el `td` obtenga el height del `tr` en el que está:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado que quiero obtener es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se puede convertir una celda de una tabla en posicionada. No funcionará como esperas. Me parece por tu pregunta que lo que quieres saber es como hacer fija una columna de una tabla. No es así?

Comment: exactamente, ¿conoces algún método? agradecería tu ayuda

Comment: Puedes poner dos tablas una encima de la otra con la tabla que queda más arriba fija a la derecha y que muestre sólo la primera columna. Si usas elementos posicionados entonces debes saberte las dimensiones de antemano.

Comment: En la tabla de ejemplo el height esta definido por la columna 4 pues el texto es mas grande, "Edad en que se realizo el registro...." (esta es la raíz del problema). ¿ Como puedo hacer que le segunda tabla tenga la misma dimensión que la primera ? (los nombres de columna vienen de una base de datos, por lo qeu su tamaño puede variar)

Comment: ¿Te planteas usar JavaScript?¿O quieres una respuesta sólo basada en HTML+CSS?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro, ya tengo una solución basada en javascript, basicamente leo el clientHeight de las columnas y obtengo el mayor con la función reduce. Actualmente busco una solución basada completamente en CSS, si es que existe.